# Ignoring github actions when automatically deploying on heroku with "Wait for CI" enabled

Tags: heroku, circleci, github-actions

### Question Summary

Is it possible to have "Wait for CI to pass before deploy" enabled on Heroku and have it wait for CircleCI only, not any Github Actions?

### Details

WE have a heroku setup linked to a github repository (not using the heroku git repo) which is set to automatically deploy from the default branch when CI (CircleCI) passes. On the github repo we have a job that runs SonarQube over the repository.

The CI job itself takes ~7 minutes, but the SonarQube job is longer, taking upwards of 15 minutes to run.

Our issue is that Heroku appears to be waiting for the GHA job to finish before running the automatic deployment, which is not what I want. Analysis is separate to tests passing.

#### Tried

Originally, the GHA job was set to autorun on pushes to master. We thought that might be the issue, so changed the setup so that the GHA job only runs on a repository action, which we then triggered from a job on CircleCI on pushes to master. So the CCI job runs to completion in seconds, leaving the GHA to run. Heroku is still waiting.

#### Ideas

- It seems sensible to trigger the deploys from CircleCI jobs after the tests have all passed, but the APIs for heroku seem more focused on deploying by pushing to heroku repos, rather than triggering a build from a github repo.
- Move completely to containerised builds rather than building on Heroku (longer term that's the plan, but we'd like to claw back the dead build time before that)

Comment: Can you post your conflig file here? If I understand correctly, you need to setup condition to deploy in the workflow section. Only if other jobs passes. You can use filter there.

Comment: If we could deploy via a trigger from CircleCI that would be ideal, but I can't find that option in the heroku API. In the current infrastructure setup, we would need to be able to trigger a build from a specific branch.

Comment: There is a requires option in circleci. Lets say your build job builds and deploy job should trigger after build. So, in workflows, for deploy add requires filter and include build job.

Comment: The CCI doesn't have a deploy job itself, though, it's configured on Heroku to automatically deploy when CI passes.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I don't think I ever did. I'm no longer working at the same job either